# Compute outliers 2 standard dev away for each pandas DataFrame column and replace with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, replace, outliers

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = 

col_1   col_2   col_3
 0.5      7       300
 0.4      4       340
 0.6      8       276
 5.6      32      764
 11.2     98      1032
```

As clearly shown above, the last two rows are outliers. I'm trying to compute the mean and standard deviation of each column. For each column, I'd like to replace any values **greater than** 2 standard deviations away with NaN. So replace outliers that are outside of the range [mean - 2 SDs, mean + 2 SDs].

I was trying to do this with `pd.DataFrame.mask` or `numpy`, but couldn't get it to work.

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to replace with NaN? If you process your data like this, you won't know if a data element was originally 0, or became 0 after this processing.

Comment: @NickODell Yes, you're right. Better to replace with NaN. Amended question above. Suggestion on best way to do this? the ```df.loc``` answer seems good.

Answer (score 2):

df.loc works best for this sort of thing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1":[0.5,0.4,0.6,5.6,11.2],
                    "col_2":[7,4,8,32,98],
                    "col_3":[300,340,276,764,1032]})

for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[col]>np.mean(df[col])+2*np.std(df[col]),col]=0
    df.loc[df[col]<np.mean(df[col])-2*np.std(df[col]),col]=0
```

```
df
Out[17]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0    0.5      7    300
1    0.4      4    340
2    0.6      8    276
3    5.6     32      0
4    0.0      0      0
```

Comment: Why do we need the ```[..., col]``` at the end?

Comment: This might be a little too literal interpretation of the question - I suspect that OP means "find outliers which are 2 std dev above or below the mean of the column."

Comment: @MAsoccer9 It does the replacement one column at a time, then loops over the columns using a `for` loop.

Comment: @NickODell Yes, that is correct. For a given column (e.g. ```col_1```), find and replace outliers that are 2 stdev above or below the mean of that column.

Comment: @NickODell So replace values that fall outside of the range [mean - 2 SD, mean + 2 SD]

Comment: Oops. Forgot to include the mean. Edited.